# Trying to combine data with different datetime stamps to closest one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to make a plot of the influence(in z direction) of an object moving in the x direction v.s. its distance of that movement in z direction.

I got three data sets which should be combined: xmovement contains the location of said object over time, locations contains the locations of three measurement points, and zmovement gives the measured results on these locations.

I'm trying to create a dataframe for every point of measurement, it should contain 2 columns: one the distance of the object from the measurement point and two the z value.

I don't know how to tackle this problem since the datetimes of the two dataframes don't correspond and therefore the nearest value should be found.

I tried working with: df.index[df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest') but I can't really grasp the way it works.

example of the datasets:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np


date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
hours = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='H')
hours1 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(1), date_today + timedelta(3), freq='H')
hours2 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(2), date_today + timedelta(5), freq='H')
hours3 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(4), date_today + timedelta(6), freq='H')

data = np.linspace(0,10,8)
xmovement = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'x': data})
xmovement.set_index('date', inplace = True)


data1 = np.linspace(0,-100,len(hours1))
data2 = np.linspace(0,-80,len(hours2))
data3 = np.linspace(0,-150,len(hours3))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours1, 'z1': data1})
df2.set_index('date', inplace = True)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours2, 'z2': data2})
df3.set_index('date', inplace = True)

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours3, 'z3': data3})
df4.set_index('date', inplace = True)

zmovement = pd.concat([df2,df3, df4], axis =1)

locations = pd.DataFrame({'point': ['df1','df2','df3'], 'x': [2,5 ,8]})
```

Comment: look into `pd.merge_asof`

Comment: Thanks didn't know about that function, this makes thinks easy. I will answer my completed code for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comment of ALollz, I managed to solve the problem. Underneath the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
hours = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='H')
hours1 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(1), date_today + timedelta(3), freq='H')
hours2 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(2), date_today + timedelta(5), freq='H')
hours3 = pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(4), date_today + timedelta(6), freq='H')

data = np.linspace(0,10,8)
xmovement = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'x': data})
xmovement.set_index('date', inplace = True)


data1 = np.linspace(0,-100,len(hours1))
data2 = np.linspace(0,-80,len(hours2))
data3 = np.linspace(0,-150,len(hours3))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours1, 'z1': data1})
df2.set_index('date', inplace = True)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours2, 'z2': data2})
df3.set_index('date', inplace = True)

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'date': hours3, 'z3': data3})
df4.set_index('date', inplace = True)

zmovement = pd.concat([df2,df3, df4], axis =1)

locations = pd.DataFrame({'point': ['df1','df2','df3'], 'x': [2,5 ,8]})


TBM_z = pd.merge_asof(xmovement,zmovement,left_index=True, right_index=True, direction = 'nearest')

dx_0 = TBM_z.x-locations.x[0]

dz_0 = TBM_z.z1

plt.scatter(dx_0, dz_0)
```